# Execute php code from template

Tags: php, html

I have the following code in PHP:

```
if ($maintenance_mode == true)
{
    $file = 'maintenance-header.php';
    $template = file_get_contents($t_includes_path . $file);
}
else
{
    $file = 'main-header.php';
    $template = file_get_contents($t_includes_path . $file);
}

require_once($s_system_path . 'templater.php');
```

And then in `templater.php`:

```
$page = str_replace(array(
    '{slang}',
    '{site_title}',
    '{site_desc}',
    '{keywords}',
    '{t_assets_path}',
    '{s_assets_path}',
    '{i_assets_path}',
    ), array(
    $slang,
    $site_title,
    $site_content,
    $keywords,
    $t_assets_path,
    $s_assets_path,
    $i_assets_path,
    ),
    $template);
echo $page;
```

The problem is that if I try to use `php` code within the template file itself it doesn't get recognized and is parsed as comments/plain text. Example:

```
if (htmlentities($_GET['lang'], ENT_QUOTES) == 'en')
{
    echo 'English';
}
else if (htmlentities($_GET['lang'], ENT_QUOTES) == 'ru')
{
    echo 'Russian';
}
else
{
    echo 'Other';
}
```

How to deal with this? I really want to use `{site_title}` instead of `<?php echo $site_title; ?>` etc. I want to keep my code as clean as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to exectue your php code. if you just 'echo' it, code that is inside your string will not be executed, just printed on the page.
you can use eval() function for example, but be sure that users can't force your web to eval() theirs code.. as mentioned on docs:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: Isn't there any other way?

Comment: well, you could force the replacement via js somehow, but i don't think users should see yours php variables

Comment: So I should abandon the concept of replacing my variables with a more readable alternative... And just go back to using standard `<?php echo $var; ?>` :(

Comment: i suppose so, there is one other alternative, but i think it's not as clear as <?php / <?= way. It is generating whole html document by php via echo.